# How To Display Specific Row Of The DataSet in The GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Table "Data".

```
  ID |  Name  |  Params   |
 --------------------------
  1  |  a     |  233      |
  22 |  a     |  34       |
  123|  a     |  123      |
  839|  a     |  2344     |
 --------------------------
```

And I use the following SQL to retrieve the data from the Table:

```
"SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name='" + Name + "'"
Adapter.Fill(Data);
DataList.Add(Data); 
Return Data;
```

Everything works if I want to display everything at once in the GridView, However, I'd like to be able to display only specific Rows of the DataSet.

**Question:**
How would I be able to display specific Row of the DataSet given an Index?

The following example shows an error:

```
Gridview.DataSource = UserDataList.Tables[0].Rows[1];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why dont you use "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Name=@Name AND where Id=@Id"
or you can add your value to a list and set the list as datasource for the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because `UserDataList.Tables[0].Rows[1]` returns a single row but the datasource of gridview expects an IEnumerable or collection of data like rows. You can filter your datatable using LINQ like this:-

```
Gridview.DataSource = UserDataList.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                  .Where((v, i) => i == 0).CopyToDataTable();
```

I have used the [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method. Here `i` is the index of rows in your table. You can fetch any row by providing the correct index. Also, one good thing is you can filter your table based on any column you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`ds` means dataset here.

using index

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
```

using column name

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["columnname"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your DataTable to DataView like

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
```

Then apply filter query like

```
dv.RowFilter = "id=10";
```

And finally convert it back to table

```
DataTable newtbl = dv.ToTable();
```

This newtbl will contain filtered data.